# MySQL interview questions row count and slow query

Tags: mysql

I've been asked these two basic MySQL interview questions:

1)-How to get the number of rows for a table
Answer:
select count and access value in schema table

interviewer: still another method, what is it?
Me: I do not know

2)- you have a query that working very well for long time then suddenly started to
slow, what should you do?
Answer, use Explain

interviewer: what else?
Me: I do not know

So what are the answer to these as I mainly developer not mysql administrator.

Comment: Dunno, but let us know when you find out

Comment: For the second Question you can also see if indexes have been dropped or modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first question all that comes to mind is the use of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS.

For example you could do:
    `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table LIMIT 20;`

After that query you could get the total row count for the selection with:
    `SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`

Now this is usually not faster then a COUNT(*) select, it is handy in case you want to use paging and need the total row count as well as the result for the current page.

On the second question I wonder if they wanted you to look at the mysql server activity. Usually if a query that used to be fast suddenly slows down that might have to do with there being a lot of insert or delete activity taking place.

Comment: thanks digaph for your answers. On the second question the interviewer confirmed that it is not mysql server admin topic but it is a software developer issue and he confirmed that the same query without any modifications to your scripts, so no inserts or deletes, just reading queries. he also confirmed that you as a developer done all optimizations.

Comment: Well I'm curious as to what it is they're after too then. If you make sure your query is using all the right indexes and the database is not having tables locked because of inserts or deletes, then I don't know either.